# Modification of Levinson algorithm for hermitian toeplitz matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have implemented Levinson algorithm for toeplitz matrix by book: Blahut "Fast algorithms for digital signal processing". Book said - modification of this algorithm for hermitian matrixes is simple job. But I could not do it. How I can modify this algorithm for hermitian toeplitz matrix?

Comment: In which step are you stuck? Can't you just replace the floats with complexes? Maybe you need to change the matrix transpose to matrix adjoint though. Let me know how it goes.